# How do i set div background image from array result using CodeIgniter

Tags: arrays, codeigniter, loops, foreach, background-image

I am a new user to using CodeIgniter in my project, I am facing one problem while showing `div background image`, there are three columns into the database where images path are stored? Now, do I display `image`, `sliderimage`, `sliderimage2` into the div background image?

**Code**

```
<?php 
   $this->db->select('*');    
   $this->db->from('sliders');
   $this->db->where('menu_id', '1');
   $data['sliders'] = $this->db->get()->result_array(); //print_r($data['sliders']); 
?>
```

**Array Result**

```
    Array ( [0] => Array ( 
    [slider_id] => 37 
    [menu_id] => 1 
    [title] => Order Now 
    [image] => /sliders/45071135132.png 
    [sliderimage] => /sliders/80540053333.png 
    [sliderimage2] => /sliders/3392955131681.png 
    [description] =>
    Offering true
    guidance to help people achieve
    their goal.

    ) )
```

**Html Code**

```
     <div class="ct-header ct-header--slider ct-slick-custom-dots" id="home">
        <div class="ct-slick-homepage" data-arrows="true" data-autoplay="true">
           <?php foreach($data['sliders'] as $slides): ?>
           <div class="ct-header tablex item" 
           data-background="<?php echo $slides['image'] ?>">
              <div class="ct-u-display-tablex">
              </div>
           </div>
           <?php endforeach ?>
        </div>
     </div>
```

**Database**

[image]

Comment: Where the images uploaded to ? Folder ?

Answer (score 0):

you have looped it, so $slides not array again, you can try `<?= $slides->image ?> or <?php echo $slides->image; ?>`

## cmiiw